# Programmatically stretch UIButton width depending on condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I've got two UIButtons into a view, which is 232px wide.

The buttons are aligned such as

```
|[BUTTON1][BUTTON1]|
|-------232px------|
```

I have a set of constraints for this alignment, but now I want to be able to change the frame of `BUTTON1`'s to full width, depending on a condition, so it'd have to be programmatically. I tried changing the frame, but since it's automatically updated, it won't work. Basically, what I want to achieve is `BUTTON1` covering `BUTTON2`, Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using autoLayout in your project, so to change the frame of your button, you have to change the constraint of you UIButton.

First make the IBOutlet of your buttons' width constraint and then when you want to change the frame of the button update that constraint like this

```
button.widthConstraint.constant = //set the constraint;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
             animations:^{
                 [self.view setNeedsLayout];
             }
             completion:^(BOOL finished) {
             }];
```

Comment: In the updated question I made my final purpose more clear. I want BUTTON1 to cover BUTTON2 (effectively making it full width). This code gives me an unable to satisfy constraint error.

Answer (score 1):

Make the outlet of button and width constraint and then

```
self.buttonWidthConstraint += 20 // adjust as per requirements
[self.myButton updateConstraints]
```

Comment: In the updated question I made my final purpose more clear. I want BUTTON1 to cover BUTTON2 (effectively making it full width). This code gives me an unable to satisfy constraint error.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the constant of the button you want **covered** to 0 and animate the change. Then the **covering** button will fill in the whole space.